# How do I get all possible HTML attributes and CSS properties of a DOM object, even unset ones?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I've seen this asked/answered many times about getting HTML properties of a DOM object, but I haven't been able to find an answer for how to get EVERY possible HTML/CSS attribute/property of an object.

Example - This will alert all the set HTML properties of the objects with id 'right_div_label'.

```
<label id='right_div_label' class='label_class' name='div_label' style='font-size: 12pt'>Label</label>

$(function () {
        $("#right_div_label").on("click", function() {
                alert($(this).attr('id'));
                var arr = [];
                for (var i = 0, attrs = $(this)[0].attributes, l = attrs.length; i < l; i++){
                    arr.push(attrs.item(i).nodeName);
                }
                alert(arr);
            }
        );
    });
```

Output looks something like - "id, class, name, style"

Now what if I wanted all possible HTML attributes that a label tag could have?  What if I wanted to know all the standard attributes such as 'dir', 'lang', 'title', etc?  Is there anyway to figure out what all of those are on a per-tag basis?  Could I feed the above function any particular tag and have it spit out something like 'This tag supports the following attributes - x, y, z'?  And what about CSS properties, could you find out those on-the-fly as well?

Comment: You could create such a function based on the HTML specification. I don't think DOM provides a way to retrieve all possible HTML attributes for a certain element. You'd have to build your own `tag->attribute` mapping function. You could also iterate over *DOM properties* of the element but they don't match HTML attributes one-to-one.

Comment: Do you need to do this programmatically?  I ask because Firebug and Webkit's Developer Tools will give you most of this information (even if it's unset).  Not all available attributes that I'm aware of, but they will give CSS properties and DOM properties (those two things can be gotten programmatically too, of course).

Comment: @ZachShipley Yes.  The reason being that I want to create a way for a user to enter an 'edit mode' of sorts where they see the page as it is normally displayed, but clicking on an element will bring up a list of possible attributes to change and changing them will show the effect in real time and save the change to the page permanently.

Comment: I think @FelixKling is right here; I've had a project in mind where I need the attribute list per element, and I don't think it exists per se in a data format. Microformats like `data-` attributes and the dichotomy of attribute vs. property introduces even greater complexity, before talking about `DOCTYPE` variance. So you need to build libraries of *properties* you want to be editable. You can get this from the W3C (see the [`label` page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-label-element.html#the-label-element)), and then you can whitelist the attributes/properties you want editable per element.

Comment: And I say *properties* due to your comment; if you want to insert *new* elements, you need the *attributes*. Not all properties are editable, so be careful there too.

Comment: This thread answers the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339367/how-to-get-all-possible-valid-attributes-on-a-dom-element/48374988#48374988